# Is ‘I walked a dog slowly’ ambiguous?

Tags: ambiguity

Is *I walked a dog slowly* ambiguous?

1. I played game and at last after 3 hours I made a dog move fast.
2. I walked a dog right away but I made a dog move slowly like a snail.

Comment: No, it's not ambiguous. Doing something slowly doesn't normally imply not doing it at all for a long time before starting - that could be conveyed by something like *I walked the dog **eventually***.

Comment: Btw, dogs move *slowly* or *quickly*: they don't move slow or fast. Some dogs are slow: others are fast.  Some words are adverbs: others are adjectives :)

Comment: In a game, I guess moving is OK.

Comment: No, it's not ambiguous. If you walk a dog slowly, it only describes how you walked the dog. It says nothing about what you were doing before. (Why do you think it does?)